# How to run Springboot app on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I am trying to run Springboot app on Tomcat server, however all of my experiments failed.

Here you can see the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringbootTomcat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringbootTomcat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Tomcat</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.SpringbootTomcat.SpringbootTomcatApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the main class:

```
package com.example.SpringbootTomcat;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringbootTomcatApplication {

//  @GetMapping("/test")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test(){
        return "Application deployed!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootTomcatApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ServletInitializer is in an other class:

```
package com.example.SpringbootTomcat;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringbootTomcatApplication.class);
    }

}
```

It is generated this way from https://start.spring.io/.

Tomcat is running on localhost:1234.

I copied the war file into `webapps` folder. However, when I type in browser `http://localhost:1234/SpringbootTomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test`, I get the following message:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/SpringbootTomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

I am running Tomcat 10.0.6 on my computer, `CATALINA_HOME` is set to folder of Tomcat, `CLASSPATH` is `CATALINA_HOME\lib`.

It only works as a Maven app but not as Tomcat application.

How can I run then the application on Tomcat Server?

Comment: Post the log of tomcat server startup

Comment: I don't think Spring Boot is compatible with Tomcat 10. Try Tomcat 9.

Comment: Tomcat 10 isn't supported as that is a JakartaEE implementation. Use Tomcat 9 which is a JEE implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be aware that by default, Spring Boot provides an embedded Apache Tomcat build, so you don't need to provide it inside IDE using a services sidebar. After that you need to be sure that your project structure follow a certain rules:

1. Don't forget that all subpackages should be locate inside your groupId default structure.
2. Also you have to check your templates structure and make sure that is set up correctly and the forwarded resource does actually exist in the given path.
3. Finally, i truly reccomend you to set `<finalName>Your final name</finalName>` inside a `<build>` tag in `pom.xml` file to avoid `/SpringbootTomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` inscription of artifact.